# How do you manage updates/rollbacks and multiples versions with AppSync and serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-appsync, aws-serverless

I'm using `AppSync` with `Lambdas`. To do so, I use the `serverless framework`.

I have few questions about the way you manage your serverless project with it's dev/test/prod versions.

I currently use the `--stage` option like `sls deploy -s test` to have multiple version. But if there is a problem after a deployment I can't `rollback` so I wonder if I should deploy with a new name all the time and remove the preview version later?

**EDIT**: I've found [this](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/rollback/) that should do it for lambdas but will that work for AppSync?

**How do you manage your dev/test/prod versions of AppSync and Lambdas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using API versions would be great except there are no cross-API subscriptions. Your mutations in one API won't trigger subscriptions in another. I'm hoping AppSync will come to support some sort of API versioning.

Not sure if serverless rollback works with AppSync, they probably should. However, it's just using serverless's S3 bucket cache, it's not a CloudFormation feature. Therefore, you could pretty much use version control to roll back changes and re-deploy just as well (your use case may vary).

We do have dev and test stages in one AWS account and prod in another AWS account. In test stage we can test that the API is working correctly before deploying it to production.

For our other deployments we also have beta stage before production but for AppSync this isn't possible because of the cross-API subscription issue. We can't have some data changing in production through beta API and not triggering a subscription in production API.

Comment: Yes that's what I was afraid of. I'm going to keep what I have today and keep waiting for a feature from AppSync. Thank you Mikuz.